# What does 側 at the end of a verb mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I haven't seen this very often at all, so this has got me stumped.

Here's an example with it showing up frequently:

http://www.orenoh.com/knowledge/mensetu-shikaku.html

The title, for example:
"未経験者を面接をする側の気持ちを考えてみる"

How do you translate this sentence, and how would you read 側 when it's used like this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

側 is read がわ in this context and it means "standpoint", "side", "party", etc., all of which amounts to "person(s) involoved" in the action described just before the 側.

> [面接]{めんせつ}をする[側]{がわ} means "interviewer(s)"
>
> 面接をされる側 means "interviewee(s)"

Thus, 「[未経験者]{みけいけんしゃ}を面接をする側の気持ちを考えてみる」 means:

> "Try(ing) to consider the feelings of those interviewing inexperienced applicants"

Comment: I knew there was some other meaning other than "side" that I've normally seen 側 for, but I couldn't quite figure it out. "person(s) involved" is what made it click for me. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

側 (がわ) is 'side', and it's being modified by the phrase before it.
You can think of the two 'sides' here as the side that does the interview, and the side is interviewed.

Although literally it's 'side', you could also think of it as 'perspective', or 'being in someone else's shoes'.

未経験者を面接をする[側] the side/perspective of those that interview people who don't have experience

You can probably figure out the rest, but I think it would be close to say "I'll try to think about how the people who interview people with no experience feel"